# Does magento and PSR provides a better way of custom logging than Zend

Tags: magento2, log, psr-logger

in previous magento version, i used to make a custom logger, using `Zend\Log\Logger` This was allowing me to create as many logger with custom name as i wanted.

I would like to update this behavior with the most recent logger `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`. But turns out, it seems to be only able to define custom filename using xml, which means i can't really have that same flexibility i had with zend; I don't just want my custom logger to have one custom log filename. I want to be able to switch that filename whenever I want, the same way I was doing it with zend `$writer = new Stream(BP . '/var/log/'.$this->filename.'.log');`

Do you see a way to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to log the files. I would suggest this type of logs to be used only for temporary purpose.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('add your log here');
```